# Laravel migrations change foreign key to be nullOnDelete() and nullable(true)

Tags: laravel, migration

I have this migration where I created a foreign key the first time:

```php
Schema::table('user_plays_quizzes', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigInteger('quiz_id')->unsigned()->change();
    $table->foreign('quiz_id')->references('id')->on('quizzes');
});
```

Now I have a new migration, where I want to update this foreign key to be `nullable(true)` and to be `nullOnDelete()`.

I tried it so many times, but there are always errors, I feel like this is the closest approach:

```php
Schema::table('user_plays_quizzes', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigInteger('quiz_id')->unsigned()->nullable(true)->change();
    $table->foreign('quiz_id')->references('id')->on('quizzes')->nullOnDelete();
});
```

Sadly it also does not work:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `d039e62e`.`user_plays_quizzes` (errno: 121
> "Duplicate key on write or update") (SQL: alter table `user_plays_quizzes` add constraint `user_plays_quizzes_quiz_id_foreign` for
> eign key (`quiz_id`) references `quizzes` (`id`) on delete set null)

No Idea how to solve it. I cant even drop the keys and recreate them aswell. Maybe someone has an idea how I can update it with a migration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you drop the key and recreate it?

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('user_plays_quizzes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        // Drop fk constraint on quiz_id column
        $table->dropForeign(['quiz_id']);
        // Alter quiz_id column
        $table->bigInteger('quiz_id')->unsigned()->nullable(true)->change();
        // Add new fk constraint on quiz_id column
        $table->foreign('quiz_id')->references('id')->on('quizzes')->nullOnDelete();

    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::table('user_plays_quizzes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        // Drop fk constraint on quiz_id column
        $table->dropForeign(['quiz_id']);
        // Restore quiz_id column to how it was before
        $table->bigInteger('quiz_id')->unsigned()->nullable(false)->change();
        // Restore original fk constraint on quiz_id column
        $table->foreign('quiz_id')->references('id')->on('quizzes');
    });
}
```